# Jquery adjust table to add tds into one row?

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I have a table which looks like the following...

```
<table width="100%" >   
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><img src="icn_pdf.gif"></td>
    <td><strong>Application Form</strong></td>
    <td><a href="/Form.pdf" class="smd"></a></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><img src="icn_pdf.gif"></td>
    <td><strong>Application Form</strong></td>
    <td><a href="/Form.pdf" class="smd"></a></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><img src="icn_pdf.gif"></td>
    <td><strong>Application Form</strong></td>
    <td><a href="/Form.pdf" class="smd"></a></td>
  </tr> 
 <tr>
    <td><img src="icn_pdf.gif"></td>
    <td><strong>Application Form</strong></td>
    <td><a href="/Form.pdf" class="smd"></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Currently you can see each 'document' on each row. What I want to do via jQuery is loop through and have two rows with two documents in. So 6 tds in each row?

Comment: Why not do this in your static HTML? Why jQuery?

Comment: Its being created dynamically via xslt which i dont know how it works

Comment: Why not learn how it works and do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/MgSsy/

```
$(function() {
    $('table tr:odd').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.prev().append(($this.html()));
        $this.remove();
    });
});​
```

I think this is what you want.

I did this as per my understanding about your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {

   $('#btn').on('click', fuction(){
     //adding to the first row
     $('#table tbody').prepend('<tr><td>...</td>...</tr>');

     //adding to the end
     $('#table tbody').append('<tr><td>...</td>...</tr>');

   }

});
```

Comment: Please add some description.